# Conditional formatting for cells when cell above has the same value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to apply conditional formatting to a whole sheet such that whenever the cell **above** the current cell has the same value (either text or number) as the current cell, the current cell will be formatted yellow fill/blue font?

For example, when cell:

A1 is *blank*
A2 AAA
A3 **AAA**
A4 **AAA**
A5 is *blank*
A6 AAA
A7 **AAA**

only cells A3, A4 and A7 will be formatted with yellow fill and font blue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While in A2, please try a Conditional Formatting formula rule of:

```
=AND(A1=A2,A2<>"")
```

with Applies to `=$2:$20` or as far down as you wish or are able to go, with yellow fill and blue font.